# SharePoint 2010 and InfoPath 2013 creating calculations from multiple fields

Tags: infopath

How can I?
I am looking at different fields in two different SharePoint List. 
Look at AvrYear1 (field from the AVRYear List), Select StateCity1 and AvrYear2 (field from the AVRYEAR List), Select StateCity (from the StateCity List) look at # entered into the Enter Amount to Escalate field/Material field from the StateCity List and put SUM in Material2 field.

AvrYear1 and AvrYear2 is in one SP List
StateCity, Material, Labor and Total are all in on SP List.